# Hide Password Content in Source Code

Tags: java, passwords, java-me

Does anyone know how to hide the password contents in the source code of a j2me program? i.e. so people cannot see "DBT" as password who read the source code.

```
public void validateUser(String user, String Password) {     
  if (user.equals("N0203251") && Password.equals("DBT")) {
    switchDisplayable(null, getContinue());
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling passwords used for auth in source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937641/handling-passwords-used-for-auth-in-source-code)

Answer (score 6):

As other have said. Store the hash, though you still need to use a strong password or an automated guesser will find the one you're using.

**But, be warned:**

If your attacker has access to the source code he/she/it can alter the stored password hash or just remove the password check.

So this method is of little use unless you can verify the integrity of the code being run, which is *hard*.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the hash (MD5 / SHA1) of the password instead and compare this with the hash of the supplied passwords.

Make sure you calculate the hash externally to avoid having the original password mentioned anywhere in the executable.

Comment: Just a little extra note - look at performing hashes / digests with the Java Cryptograpy Architecture http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#MessageDigest

Comment: You contradicted yourself. In para #1, you say store the hash. In para #2, you say calculate the hash.

Comment: @GregS: There is no contradiction here. At build time you calculate the hash from a file or other source not part of the source code, and generate code from that calculation which stores only the hash in the executable. The at run time you calculate the hash of the user input and compare that to the correct hash stored in the program (probably in the data segment).

Comment: @Gregs - It says "calculate the hash *externally*", and by that I mean use another tool outside of the source code to generate the hash.  If you've any suggestion how to word it better, I'm open to offers!

Comment: @dmckee: Thank you, I misunderstood that. Even so, I maintain my claim stated below.

Answer (score 3):

**When it comes down to it, you've written a back door into the program.  That's a Bad Thing - don't do it.**

Like others have said, you can do better by using a hash, but a couple critical things are left out. When someone guesses the password, they'll know the password for every installed copy of your software.  Since the password is hard coded, nobody will be able to change it or revoke it, so you'll have inserted a back door in the program that nobody can eliminate.  And if you rely on that password ofr any communication with other resources, you can't ever change it - at least, not without significant additional work.

What you should really do is place the password in an external location, such as a hardware security module, or password file, or database table.  Then, implement a full password change and rotation mechanism - honestly, this should be pretty much the same mechanism you use across all your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that [hashes the password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) - keep the hash of a password in the source, not the password itself.

A quote from that page:

> A related application is password
>   verification. Passwords are usually
>   not stored in cleartext, for obvious
>   reasons, but instead in digest form.
>   To authenticate a user, the password
>   presented by the user is hashed and
>   compared with the stored hash. This is
>   sometimes referred to as one-way
>   encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the application on the user's mobile device, the best you can do is try to obscure the password. I would recommend doing some sort of hashing algorithm (maybe SHA1) or a key derivation algorithm like PBKDF2 and storing the result rather than comparing against the plaintext password.

Answer (score -1):

Storing the hash instead the password buys you absolutely nothing. Since it is now the hash being used to authenticate instead of the password, reading the source code (or reversing the object code) will reveal the hash and allow the attacker to authenticate.

The answer to these questions is always the same. You can't achieve any measurable security if you use hard-coded client-side secrets no matter what you do. The best you can do is obfuscate enough until you get a warm fuzzy feeling that it is good enough.

Comment: If user password input is hashed, knowing the desired hash does you absolutely no good (assuming the original password is "strong enough"). Saying "hashing buys you nothing" is simply false. If the user can Modify the code, you're obviously hosed, but just knowing the correct hash doesn't mean you can simply provide that, as you're implying.

Comment: The user can *always* modify the code running on their computer or appliance, and almost always very easily. Hashing buys you no measurable increase in security, only a non-measurable warm fuzzy feeling of false security.

Comment: In compiled programs (which I guess would be a jar in javaese), it is slightly easier to read a plain text password than to locate the test and hack it out. A very modest defense suitable for kid sisters.

Comment: what are you talking about, GregS? given the hash of a password, if it's a good hash function, the attacker can not make up the password that will match this hash. This is how Unix stored its passwords for a long time (with the addition of salting, but that's not salient for this discussion)

Comment: @eli: True, I know that. Rereading the original code carefully instead of jumping to conclusions, I see my answer doesn't make sense. Instead of editing it, I leave it there as ignominious monument. The hash doesn't buy you anything in terms of keeping users besides "N0203251" from being able to derive the benefits of switchDisplayable(...), but not for the reasons I stated.

Comment: Greg, what a great attitude, we all have our moments!