# How to hide password within JAR file

Tags: java, jar, passwords, password-encryption

I am trying to make a Java program that requires a password. The problem is that a Java class or JAR file can be converted back to source code, so people can see the password by converting the program back to source code. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling passwords used for auth in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937641/handling-passwords-used-for-auth-in-source-code)

Comment: *why* does your jar have a pw inside of it? There is no way to secure the password.

Comment: If I don't store the password in the JAR then where should I store it? (I am still learning programming)

Comment: What is the password for? Probably to access *something* one the web. For that you generally have two alternatives: make the service open to everyone (who knows it) or have a per-user authentication (via achosen password, or client certificate or ...). Having *one* password in the jar defeats the purpose of the password since now "everyone" has it, can use it which means you could have skipped it to begin with. Storing that user credentials on the client pc is an entirely different topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Even if you encrypt the password, the code to decrypt the password will be available in, and so will not prevent someone decompiling your application.

You have some options:

- Put your password in an environment variable (accessible with `System.getProperty("variable.name")`)
- Store the password in a file (still not great, but better than sources)
- Access the password from a server, however, you are still required to make the user enter their creds for the server, and now you're left with the same problem.
- Make the user enter a password every time they run the application

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to protect the password is to use a `one-way hash`.  I would recommend investigating the `Secure Hash Algorithms (SHA)`.  These are one-way hashes (aka `cryptographic checksums`) that generate, for all practical purposes, a unique hash for some given text or message.  Store the hash in the JAR file and the use the same algorithm to hash the entered password. Compare that hash to the stored one for verification.

The down side to this is that it is not easy (or in some cases possible) to change the password.

The odds of generating identical hashes for different inputs is infinitesimal.

Here is one way it could be done using standard Java libraries.

```java
      MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
      String password = "Password"; // password to be "stored"
      byte[] bytes = password.getBytes();

      md.update(bytes);
      byte[] digest = md.digest();

      // store the following string in the jar file
      String storedDigest = toHex(digest);

      // validation process
      String enteredPassword = "Password";
      md.update(enteredPassword.getBytes());
      System.out.println(toHex(md.digest()).equals(storedDigest) ? "Passed"
            : "Failed");

   //Convert array of bytes to a long hex string
   public static String toHex(byte[] digest) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (byte b : digest) {
         sb.append(Integer.toHexString((b >> 4) & 0xF));
         sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xF));
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }
```