# Hide plain text Credentials on Java

Tags: java, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have a username and password in my Java app to call an external API. I would like obfuscate these credentials' strings and not hardcode them in plain text inside source code.

Any tip how I can do that?

Comment: I would argue against ever saving credentials hard-coded, even if obfuscated. That's a recipe for desaster. However, there are lots of options. Simple Ceasar comes to mind first. Or make some sort of Enigma-machine.

Comment: you should externalize these as command line arguments.

Comment: [Handling passwords used for auth in source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12937641/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials are in an app on an insecure client device, then there is no way to secure them 100%. The common solution is to avoid storing username/password but instead have the user login once to obtain a token from the (secure) application server. This token is stored on the insecure device as securely as feasible, and refreshed on a regular basis: When the token nearly expires, it is used to authenticate with the server and obtain a new token. In this way, if the token is stolen it will not grant access indefinitely.

Comment: I know is not the most correct way to have some security, but at this point i just like to obfuscate the plain text string's

Comment: You could apply Base64 encoding. But you have to promise that this does not go into production :-)